# Picture expanding with jQuery animation pushes others

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm working on an eCommerce website, and my client wants the product images to be expandable on hover on the category page.

The product images are organized in `<li>`s inside of a `<ul>` and I have them set up so that there's 4 in each row to make it look like a grid. Its all just one big `<ul>` though.

I have animated the pictures with jQuery to expand downwards and reveal the whole image (the image's size is 185 x 380 but before you hover you see it cropped at 185 x 185) but when it expands it pushes the other `<li>`s to the side and it becomes a mess.

How can I have my `<li>`s images expand without pushing any of the surrounding elements.

Here is my jquery code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".item").hover(function() {
      $(this).find('.image').stop().animate({height: "380px"}, 'slow');
      $(this).find('.product-info').fadeIn();
    },
    function() {
      $(this).find('.image').stop().animate({height: "185px"}, 'slow');
      $(this).find('.product-info').fadeOut();
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: a jsfiddle would be useful here. Also, you probably want to float it or adjust the z-index or *something* to pull it out of the page first. What have you tried?

Comment: I agree with @Colleen, I have solved almost an identical problem by making a dummy div that is hidden until I want to expand the item. Then when I expand I move the item to position absolute and push the dummy into the visible DOM so that the space it used to occupy is not lost. the effect you get is that the item expands but the visible tree stays put.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would set the width and height of the li element and when you animate the img inside of it, the li elements stay in place.

```
#list li {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

See the fiddle for full example:
http://jsfiddle.net/rP4aU/

Comment: Yes, I was actually thinking of changing the z-index, thanks a lot!

Comment: You just missed position:relative in the img.active { } when I added it worked perfectly !